# Can this hard drive's file system be repaired?

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, filesystem, fdisk

I think I have a possible file system issue which I hope a file system repair can fix.

Here are the details of the hard drive in question:

[image: one.png]

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x86660137

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       1001470 976771071 975769602 465.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1001472 976771071 975769600 465.3G 83 Linux
```

If I type in the passphrase to unlock the hard drive, here are the details to show that difference before and after unlocking:

[image: three.png]

```
Disk /dev/mapper/luks-58c8286c-2472-411b-88b8-69d7032e0b13: 465.3 GiB, 499591938048 bytes, 975765504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

When I go to Nautilus to try to get into the unlocked drive, the drive is not visible in nautilus at all.

**However!** If I lock the hard drive again, I can see the drive listed in Nautilus:

[image: five.png]

If I then click the drive in Nautilus, it asks for the passphrase as expected:

[image: six.png]

After typing in the passphrase, it shows this message, and the drive is no longer shown in nautilus:

[image: seven.png]

I am hoping to get the hard drive into a state, which at least allows me to copy the files off and save to another file system.

---

**Edit 1:** As requested by ridgy, outputs from vgscan and lvscan:

```
userone@userone:~$ sudo vgscan
[sudo] password for userone: 
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
userone@userone:~$ sudo lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/root' [43.22 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1' [15.92 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/ubuntu-vg/root' [457.34 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1' [7.94 GiB] inherit
userone@userone:~$
```

---

**Edit 2:** As requested by ridgy, output from vgdisplay:

```
userone@userone:~$ sudo vgdisplay
[sudo] password for userone: 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               59.14 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              15141
  Alloc PE / Size       15139 / 59.14 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       2 / 8.00 MiB
  VG UUID               pf9z1Z-02zv-5BRD-jkbI-YhDN-SrQA-DrnRND

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               465.28 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              119111
  Alloc PE / Size       119111 / 465.28 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               NwOoOV-ne4y-JeyM-7Sl7-SF7n-0INf-TkEcH3
```

---

**The Question: What's the recommended way of attempting to correct this issue.**

Comment: After unlocking the partition, there is a LVM "physical volume" shown. Please add the output of `sudo pvscan`, `sudo vgscan` and `sudo lvscan` to your question.

Comment: @ridgy, outputs added to OP as requested.

Comment: The reason for the problem are two volume groups with same name (one on sda, which seems to be the active system, and one on sdb). I suppose the disk which is now sdb was a former ubuntu installation. To access the data we have to rename the volume group on sdb. Please add the output of `sudo vgdisplay` to your question, so I can give specific advice.

Comment: @ridgy, output of vgdisplay added to OP as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need to rename the second volume group (on sdb2). As the name is not unique, we use the UUID for renaming:

```
sudo vgrename NwOoOV-ne4y-JeyM-7Sl7-SF7n-0INf-TkEcH3 decrypt-vg
```

where `NwOoOV-ne4y-JeyM-7Sl7-SF7n-0INf-TkEcH3` is the UUID (see your output of `vgdisplay`), and `decrypt-vg`is the new name; you could chose any name as you like, as long as it differs from the one of any existing volume group.

`man vgrename` gives a short description why this is necessary, and few examples.

The logical volumes shown by `lvscan` should now be active, and the device nodes created and mountable.